# Best pdf library for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation

I have a requirement to create pdfs with tables. I started it by using prawn. But it was too slow and kept utilizing 100% CPU. Now I moved to wicked_pdf.

This is much faster than prawn but still could be faster. One of my friend recommended TCPDF.

I found [rfpdf gem](https://github.com/edwinmoss/rfpdf) which is TCPDF plugin for rails. Have anyone here used it before? How fast is it?

I also found [fpdf](http://source.mihelac.org/2006/06/19/creating-pdf-documents-with-tables-in-ruby-rails/). Are they better than wicked_pdf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'wicked_pdf' gem. It provides very good support to generate pdf using html code.
https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf

In controller:

```
def show
  @report = Report.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.pdf do
      render :pdf => "report",:template => "reports/show"
    end 
  end
end
```

Create a show.pdf.erb and you can write simple html.

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<h1> Report </h1>
<p>
<%= @report.details %>
.................................
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [PdfKIT](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit), it's awesome and very simple to use. [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit) is a screencast for it.

Comment: How is this different from wicked_pdf? Both are wrappers around wkhtmltopdf. Is this faster than wicked_pdf?

Answer (score 0):

You don't state the format of your source material.  If you are starting from simple text documents, HTML, or other simple markup formats, then you may wish to have a look at [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc).  This tool will let you convert simple document types into a number of publication-type formats, including PDF.

Since you have a requirement to produce tables in your PDF files, one easy option would be to create your documents in [Markdown format](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), which includes simple rules for creating tables.  See this [cheat sheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#wiki-tables) for an example.

Finally, here is a [blog post](http://jonmifsud.com/blog/writing-in-markdown-and-converting-markdown-to-pdf/) I read recently that discusses converting Markdown documents to PDF files.

Since you are working with Rails there also exists a [lightweight wrapper](https://github.com/alphabetum/pandoc-ruby) for Pandoc that might prove useful.

Comment: I have to generate a pdf with table that has 20k records. Right now i am using wicked_pdf which converts the html file into pdf. Wouldn't it be overhead to convert the markdown format to html and then to pdf?

Comment: Vimsha, I suppose with that many records you do want avoid extra data conversions.  My initial motivation for Markdown format is that it is so simple to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look also on another gem: https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_pdf

It's using chrome headless to create PDF.